# Deleting graphics from Go To XY and Add Labeled Point?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, delete, graphics

How do I delete a green point with coordinates that I added to my map using Go to x,y / Add Labelled Point?

Answer (score 10):

You can do this by using the Select tool from the Draw toolbar to select that graphic element, then hit the Delete key to delete it.

If you want to delete all such graphics use Edit | Select All Elements to do the selection step.

Comment: Thanks PolyGeo.

I worked!

However, I would like to add here that the thing with Edit / select all elements works only in the data view. once you are in the data view, with that selection, you can select and delete the green point 

Many thanks

Comment: You can still access, edit and modify data frame graphics from the layout view by clicking the "Focus Data Frame" button which highlights the target data frame in Layout so that any graphics drawn and edited within the focused area are carried out within the particular map object's graphics container. These graphics will inherit the coordinate system of that data frame.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this same issue but in ArcGIS Pro.  I found that when adding points (Mark Location) from the Go To XY tool, in order to delete those points, you need to go the the Map Graphics tab, use the Select tool there, select the point or points you added, right click on your mouse and then you will have the option to delete them from your map.

Answer (score -2):

simple click select all element from edit menu and press delete

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  A good answer should include steps involved and be as descriptive as possible.  How does this answer provide any more information than the answer already provided above?